# PC not recognize usb after modification

Tags: usb-flash-drive

i have and product consists an USB port. For a reason, we have to modify the line from product to PC to another port (B) as attachment ( i made it in simple circuit). Even though the USB port B not connect or short circuit as i checked, but PC just recognize the USB A if i disconnect the DP and DN signal to USB B ( if i connect DP and DM to USB port B , then windows will pop up "USB malfunction , can't recognize"). Can someone educate me this case?

Image:
[image]

Comment: This is a classic [XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You have an issue that you haven't disclosed and which you want to solve. You came up with a weird solution (adding a 2nd USB plug) and now you have a different problem caused by your solution. What was the original problem? Why do you think you need two USB plugs?

Comment: USB signals are not intended for use on cables like this. While it may technically work the signals may be degraded. You should get a device such as this https://www.amazon.co.uk/Selector-Switcher-One-Button-Swapping-Keyboard-Black/dp/B07S5H6T18 to swap a USB device between computers. You should never have the potential of simultaneously having two computers connected like this, bad things can happen if you don't do it properly.

Comment: Connecting two PC's *directly* through their USB ports likely destroyed one or both ports. Consider that both ports have DC power lines, and if there is a difference of even a millivolt, one power supply is trying to raise voltage as the other tries to limit it -- causing high currents to flow, beyond their specs. As @Mokubai states, there are switches to provide that utility.

Comment: i have a test kit to test the usb port but there's a short term ultility on port A for manual testing, but there'll be a new fixture coming. so i modified the kit to make port B for readiness but not use for now, but after i modified, port A can not be recognized anymore. I just use one port at a time.